# Fix a memory leak in java web application that has axis2 and struts?

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, apache-axis

I have analyzed the web application and found that some classes where not being removed from memory after garbage collector has run. Below is the screenshot 
[Screenshot of objects in memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCAcd.png)

And when I analyzed what was holding those objects, I found that a class in axis2 had a static reference to them. (static cache of class org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl". Below is the screenshot

[Screenshot of the class holding from GC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJSFB.png)

Comment: try accessing it via reflection and clear the cache?

Comment: encountering the same issue. Any pointers so far?